# How to parametrize data in a CDATA section

Tags: xml, vb.net, cdata

I know I can add text to a CDATA section like this in vb.net:

```
Dim temp As System.Xml.Linq.XCData = <![CDATA[Hello World!]]>
```

but how do I pass in a parameter value:

```
Dim myValue as string = "Hello World!"
Dim temp As System.Xml.Linq.XCData = <![CDATA[myValue]]>
```

I know I can do this, but is this the right way to do it?

```
Dim myValue as string = "Hello World!"
Dim temp As New System.Xml.Linq.XCData("<![CDATA[" & myValue & "]]>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give the string value to XCData constructor il will put the CDATA tag by itself

```
    Dim myValue As String = "Hello World!"
    Dim temp As New XCData(myValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

It works like this:

```
Dim myValue as string = "Hello World!"
Dim temp As System.Xml.Linq.XCData = <![CDATA[<%= myValue %>]]>
```

For reference: [MSDN (How to: Embed Expressions in XML Literals (Visual Basic))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384752.aspx)

**EDIT**: So that does not work, because CDATA does not allow any embedded expressions. See: [MSDN (XML CDATA Literal (Visual Basic))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384869.aspx#Anchor_3)

So you are left with the constructor of `XCData`:

```
Dim myValue As String = "Hello World!"
Dim temp As New XCData(myValue)
```

You can use both.

The visual basic compiler actually just converts a CDATA literal like

```
Dim temp = <![CDATA[foo]]>
```

to

```
Dim temp = New XCData("foo")
```

Comment: Won't work CDATA tag treat all content as text. It will contains exactly the text entered here it will be `<%= myValue %>` without processing it

Comment: @Sehnsucht: You are correct. I spoke too soon. Fixed the answer. Thank you.